# database import and export in mongodb idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoimport

I type

```
`mongo`
```

in terminal it connects to mongodb.
I have many database and collection there.
I want to export my

```
 `hero` (dbs name)
```

and its collection

```
users
```

to a desktop in new folder.
By copying that folder and paste in another computer, I want to import that

```
`hero(dbs name)`
```

and its collection.
Now when i type

```
show dbs
```

then there should be

```
`hero`
```

in my second computer. How can i do this. 
I use mongodump also.
can anyone give me the idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good manual page from 10gen showing example commands and what not for doing what you want: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/#database-dumps and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodump .

So an example for you would be (to copy the collection):

```
mongodump --collection hero --database name
```

And then to restore it on the other computer after copying the output of the above command to the current folder where mongorestore is held:

```
mongorestore --collection hero --database name
```

I am unsure what OS you are using as such I have placed these in Linux command syntax.

Comment: I am also using linux. i just want to export my database hero in desktop in certain folder. By using mongo dump it is copied in /var/lib/mongodb but i want to copied in my own folder in desktop and export it to the another computer from that folder.

Comment: @regmiprem I would personally say export the folder created in `var/lib/mongodb` is there a particular reason you need to copied to desktop, sounds like an uneeded step

Comment: ok can u give me the guide so that i can export my hero dbs in /var/lib/mongodb and paste into other computer /var/lib/mongodb and when i run show dbs in next com i command (show dbs)I can see hero there?

Comment: prem@gobingoo:~$ mongodump --collection hero --database name
(ERROR: unknown option database

Export MongoDB data to BSON files.)
I get this in my terminal when i enter ur command.

Comment: @regmiprem Just run mongodump as shown above then copy the `dump/` folder in its enterity to your remote `/var/lib/mongodb` then run the second command. try: `mongodump -c hero -d name` it seems the command has changed between 2.0 and 2.2

Comment: ya tahnks i find dump folder and inside dump folder i copy the hero folder. now i paste this filder inside /var/lib/mongodb and run the command u describe above but it gives name dbs with empty. i am so close to the solution.

Comment: @regmiprem yea try this: `mongorestore -d name -c hero` since the command is different again cos of your mongodb version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15045/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-sammaye)

Comment: Thanks for ur support> I got it.

Comment: anyone can visit this site and feedback is welcome. simple blog i made  http://erpremregmi.blogspot.com/2012/08/save-and-restore-database-in-mongodb.html